# What is the difference between "play speed" and "playback speed"?

Tags: meaning, difference, expressions

In my opinion, "playback" is just like "replay", am I right? But mostly people say "playback speed". I think they mean the play speed, why the "back" should be added behind "play"? What is the difference?

Comment: Identical question (not by this user) on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30359/explanation-for-to-playback-media-content)

Comment: Here is the answer,it's provided by @Catija. 
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30359/explanation-for-to-playback-media-content

Answer (score 1):

:)

No, they are correct when they say playback.

In order to help you understand it, I'll try to explain how I intuitively understand it.

When you record something on a media, you are effectively *putting stuff* on it (video, audio, other files, ...). Then, at the moment when you want to consume the data, you will need to operate the device in order to make the device "give the content *back* to you" (your eyes, ears, or any other non-standard limbs you might have ;) ). So play-back, which implies that earlier in time a contrary operation (storing the content) took place.

Also usually we store stuff in an ordered way (i.e. a video is a set of many pictures ordered in time), so the expression "play it back" perhaps also comes from the implicit understanding that we need to go *back* to the start of it (yes, once you had to actually rewind a tape), before being able to play it..

Answer (score 0):

[*"Playback"*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/playback) means :

> the reproduction of previously recorded sounds or moving images.

This simply means *"playing"* an audio or video that was recorded earlier. Now the *"back"* can be edited in most contexts. It is simply used to show that the track was recorded earlier, or *"long back"*. It's a form of replaying a piece of recording. Maybe that's why *"back"* is used. 
But there are occasions where you cannot replace *"playback"* with *"re-play"* or *"play"*:

> He was a renowned **playback** singer, back in the 80's.

Now, you cannot say *'he was a "play" singer'*. That just sounds odd. Technically, it means the same - **You record. You play,** but they cannot be interchanged in all contexts.